# How to make an Angular material tab transparent?

Tags: sass, angular8

I'm doing an angular page and I can't find a way of making the angular material tabs transparent. This is the HTML code:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar backgroundColor="primary" color="primary">
  <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" [routerLink]="link.link" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>
```

I've already tried:

```
.mat-tab-link {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

which makes all my mat-tabs transparent. And I just need to make the background transparent, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `background` property and use the alpha channel when setting the color:

```
.mat-tab-link {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: I think you're close to the solution. my tabs are transparent but my  `mat-tab-nav-bar` isn't transparent.

Comment: @P.Aneyba You are setting the background of the tab bar to your primary color. If you don't set that to a color then it will be transparent too.

Comment: That was it. Damn.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bootstrap you can add the `.bg-transparent` class to your `nav` like so

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar backgroundColor="primary" color="primary" class="bg-transparent">
```

You can find more details [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/colors/).

Comment: I've tried this. Didn't change anything. Do angular material design components interact with bootstrap class modifiers?

Comment: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/ maybe this could fit your needs